# Converting Char array to Long in C error

Tags: c, arrays, char, converters

I try to covert unsigned long int to char
but I got some error

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char pdest[4];
    unsigned long l=0xFFFFFFFF;
    pdest[0] = l         & 0xFF;
    pdest[1] = (l >>  8) & 0xFF;
    pdest[2] = (l >> 16) & 0xFF;
    pdest[3] = (l >> 24) & 0xFF;

    unsigned long int l1=0;
    l1 |= (pdest[0]);
    l1 |= (pdest[1] << 8);
    l1 |= (pdest[2] << 16);
    l1 |= (pdest[3] << 24);

    printf ("%lu",l1);
}
```

and output is

```
18446744073709551615
```

not 4294967295?

How to do it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

> ...Long unsigned integer type. Capable of containing **at least** the [0,
>   4,294,967,295] range;

Answer (score 0):

You should write the last 4 lines as:

```
l1 |= ((unsigned long) pdest[0]);
l1 |= (((unsigned long) pdest[1]) << 8);
l1 |= (((unsigned long) pdest[2]) << 16);
l1 |= (((unsigned long) pdest[3]) << 24);
```

As you should cast the byte to unsigned long before shifting.

Answer (score 0):

pdest[3] << 24 is of type signed int.

Change your code to

```
unsigned long int l1=0;
l1 |= (pdest[0]);
l1 |= (pdest[1] << 8); 
l1 |= (pdest[2] << 16);
l1 |= ((unsigned int)pdest[3] << 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the shifting of char. You must force a conversion to unsigned long before to shift beyond the 8 bits of a char. Moreover the sign of char will play a further alteration on the result.

Try

```
unsigned long int l1=0;
l1 |= ((unsigned long)pdest[0]);
l1 |= ((unsigned long)pdest[1] << 8); 
l1 |= ((unsigned long)pdest[2] << 16); 
l1 |= ((unsigned long)pdest[3] << 24);
```

Note the use of a cast to force compilers to convert the char to an unsigned long before that the shift take place.

Answer (score 0):

Your unsigned long does not have to be 4 bytes long.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    int index;
    unsigned char pdest[sizeof(unsigned long)];
    unsigned long l=0xFFFFFFFFUL;

    for(index = 0; index < sizeof(unsigned long); index++)
    {
        pdest[index] = l & 0xff;
        l >>= 8;
    }

    unsigned long l1=0;
    for(index = 0; index < sizeof(unsigned long); index++)
    {
        l1 |= (unsigned long)pdest[index] << (8 * index);

    }

    printf ("%lx\n",l1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to name a type that is exactly 32 bits wide, use `uint32_t`, not `unsigned long int`. `unsigned long int` is generally 64 bits wide in 64-bit *nixes (so called LP64), whereas they're 32 bits in Windows (LLP64).

Anyway, the problem is with *integer promotions*. An operand to a arithmetic operation with conversion rank less than `int` or `unsigned int` will be converted to `int` or `unsigned int`, whichever its range fits into. Since all `unsigned char`s are representible as `signed int`s, the `pdest[3]` is converted to `signed int` and the result of `pdest[3] << 24` is also of type `signed int`!. Now, if that has the most significant bit set, the bit is shifted into the sign bit of the integer, and the behaviour is according to the C standard, *undefined*.

However, GCC has defined behaviour for this case; in there, the result is just a negative integer with 2's complement representation; therefore the result of `(unsigned char)0xFF << 24` is `(int)-16777216`. Now, for `|` operation this then needs to be promoted to the rank of the *other* operand, which is `unsigned`. The unsigned conversion happens as if by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum (i.e. repeatedly adding or subtracting 2⁶⁴) until the value fits in the range of the value. Since `unsigned long` is 64 bits on your platform, the result of this conversion is 2^64 - 16777216, or 18446744073692774400, which is ORred with the bits from previous steps.

How to fix? Easy, just prior to shifts, cast each shifted number to `uint32_t`. Print with the help of `PRIu32` macro:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

...

uint32_t l1=0;
l1 |= (uint32_t)pdest[0];
l1 |= (uint32_t)pdest[1] << 8;
l1 |= (uint32_t)pdest[2] << 16;
l1 |= (uint32_t)pdest[3] << 24;
printf ("%" PRIu32, l1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is implicit type conversions of unsigned char to int and then to unsigned long with signed extension for bitwise or operation, the corresponding values for each lines are as commented below

```
l1 |= (pdest[0]);   //dec = 255 hex = 0xFF
l1 |= (pdest[1] << 8);   //dec = 65535 hex = 0xFFFF
l1 |= (pdest[2] << 16);  //dec = 16777215 hex =0xFFFFFF
l1 |= (pdest[3] << 24);  //here is the problem
```

In last line `pdest[3] << 24 = 0xFF000000` which is equivalent to `-16777216` due to implicit conversion to int. It is again converted to unsigned long for bitwise or operation, where signed extension happens in `l1 |= (pdest[3] << 24)` which is equivalent to `0x0000000000FFFFFF | 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000`.

As many people suggested you can use explicit type conversion or you can use below code snippet,

```
l1 = (l1 << 0) | pdest[3];
l1 = (l1 << 8) | pdest[2];
l1 = (l1 << 8) | pdest[1];
l1 = (l1 << 8) | pdest[0];
```

I hope it solves your problem and reasons out for such a huge output.